# From Facebook URL redirect into XAMPP page

Tags: facebook, url, xampp

helo guys, can you help me with this problem. My facebook URL was ok but when i installed xampp program in my pc it turned out that it affects my fb URL. After i type https://www.facebook.com, the browser will redirect me to the localhost. I will show you the images for you to understand more. Please help me. I know it is not coding problem but it involves something that other may experienced. Thanks in advance.

[image: the first one to appear]

[image: and the second one after clicking proceed anyway]

please help me.